# how to pass the "id" argument of the jquery element to a function that has an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

So I created a function to update data using ajax jquery, so that the code is shorter and can be used over and over again. as in the code below:

```
$.fn.myUpdateConfig = function({
  formcomp: formcomp,
  urlcomp: urlcomp,
  errorcomp: errorcomp,
  editcomp: editcomp,
  id: id,
  beforeajaxcallb: beforeAjaxCallb = null,
  successcallb: successCallb = null,
  errorcallb: errorCallb = null,
  completecallb: completeCallb = null,
}) {
  let element = $(this);
  element.click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let formdata = new FormData(formcomp[0]);
      formdata.append('_method', 'PUT');
      formValidation('hide', '', [errorcomp, editcomp]);
      element.addClass('btn-progress');
      loader.show();

      console.log(id)); //parameter "id" returns an empty value

    if (beforeAjaxCallb instanceof Function) beforeAjaxCallb();

    $.ajax({
      url: urlcomp + id,
      data: formdata,
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {
        formValidation('hide', '', [errorcomp, editcomp]);
        succSwallTimer(data.message);
        if (successCallb instanceof Function) successCallb();
      },
      error: function(data) {
        errorMessage(data, errorcomp, editcomp);
        if (errorCallb instanceof Function) errorCallb();
      },
      complete: function() {
        element.removeClass('btn-progress');
        loader.hide();
        if (completeCallb instanceof Function) completeCallb();
      }
    });
  });
};
```

In the commented section `console.log(id));`, the parameter "id" returns an empty value, so it returns an error "405 The PUT method is not supported for this route" because no id was sent.
[image]

the following below is a function call:

```
$('#updateBtn').myUpdateConfig({
  formcomp: Vdef.formcomp.update,
  urlcomp: Vdef.urlcomp,
  errorcomp: Vdef.errorcomp.update,
  editcomp: Vdef.editcomp,
  id: $('#edit_id').val(),
  successcallb: function() {
    $('#editModal').modal('hide');
    Vdef.formcomp.update.trigger('reset');
  },
  completecallb: function() {
    table.draw();
  }
});
```

but when I pass just the $ `('#edit_id')` argument without val(), it returns a jquery object.
[image]
result:
[image]
and
[image]

result:
[image]

So what I want is how to pass the "id" argument taken from `$('#edit_id').val()` which can be passed to the `myUpdateConfig()`

Comment: You're setting `id` when you initialize the widget, not when the user clicks.

Comment: yes it is like that, is there a way to call that function after the user clicks the button

Comment: Because, it is an update function, so actually there is an edit button (setting data to input) including the $ ('# edit_id'), before the update button is clicked.

Comment: I didn't ask a question, what is that the answer to? I posted a solution below several minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the value of `#edit_id` when you initialize the widget, not when the user clicks on the update button.

Change it so you pass the selector to the widget, and get the value in the event listener.

```
$.fn.myUpdateConfig = function({
  formcomp: formcomp,
  urlcomp: urlcomp,
  errorcomp: errorcomp,
  editcomp: editcomp,
  selector: selector, // replacing id: id
  beforeajaxcallb: beforeAjaxCallb = null,
  successcallb: successCallb = null,
  errorcallb: errorCallb = null,
  completecallb: completeCallb = null,
}) {
  let element = $(this);
  element.click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let formdata = new FormData(formcomp[0]);
      formdata.append('_method', 'PUT');
      formValidation('hide', '', [errorcomp, editcomp]);
      element.addClass('btn-progress');
      loader.show();
      let id = $(selector).val(); // Get value of input
      console.log(id));
    if (beforeAjaxCallb instanceof Function) beforeAjaxCallb();

    $.ajax({
      url: urlcomp + id,
      data: formdata,
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {
        formValidation('hide', '', [errorcomp, editcomp]);
        succSwallTimer(data.message);
        if (successCallb instanceof Function) successCallb();
      },
      error: function(data) {
        errorMessage(data, errorcomp, editcomp);
        if (errorCallb instanceof Function) errorCallb();
      },
      complete: function() {
        element.removeClass('btn-progress');
        loader.hide();
        if (completeCallb instanceof Function) completeCallb();
      }
    });
  });
};

$('#updateBtn').myUpdateConfig({
  formcomp: Vdef.formcomp.update,
  urlcomp: Vdef.urlcomp,
  errorcomp: Vdef.errorcomp.update,
  editcomp: Vdef.editcomp,
  selector: '#edit_id', // replacing id: $("#edit_id").val()
  successcallb: function() {
    $('#editModal').modal('hide');
    Vdef.formcomp.update.trigger('reset');
  },
  completecallb: function() {
    table.draw();
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that there are several calls to the ```myUpdateConfig()``` function that pass the "id" argument by passing PHP for example ```id: "<?= $member ('id') ?>"``` So it's not all selector

Comment: Change that to `selector: "#<?= $member('id') ?>"`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$member['id']`? And how is that putting `$('#edit_id').val()` into the JavaScript that's causing the problem?

Comment: yes, that's right $ member ['id'] is not $ member ('id'), so in a different view I put "<?= $member['id'] ?>" to "id"

Comment: So do like I said: `"#<?= $member['id'] ?>"`

Comment: I still don't see how that's generating the code you showed in the question. Where is `.val()` coming from in that?

Comment: okay, so ```$('#edit_id').val()``` takes the value from ```<input type="hidden" id="edit_id" name="id">``` which is in the "edit form"

Comment: sorry, "#<?= $member['id'] ?>" its not working

Comment: so <?= $member['id'] ?> is a "member id" which is a direct value id, not a selector

Comment: And that's why I put `#` before it when putting it into the JS.

Comment: If `$member['id']` is `edit_id`, then `"#<?= $member['id'] ?>"` will be `"#edit_id"`

Comment: What do you see when you use `View Source` to see the resulting JavaScript?

Comment: no, edit_id is't $member['id'], $member['id']. I mean in some cases I use to put id directly with "$ member ['id']" so the resulting parameter "id: 2" is not a selector or anything

Comment: for $('#edit_id').val(), When I use the modal dialog, when the button on the table is clicked it will set the value including #edit_id ', so when the update button is clicked I just take it with the code $('#edit_id ').val ()

Comment: Then it seems like you need two parameters: `id:` and `selector:`. Then you need to check which one was set, and get the id accordingly.

Comment: Another solution some widgets use is to allow a parameter to be a value or a function. If it's a function, the widget will call the function whenever it needs the value.

Comment: E.g. `let actual_id = typeof id == "function" ? id.call(element) : id;`

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm using in my custom function ```id = (typeof id == "function" ? id().val() : id);``` while in function calls using ```id: function () { return $('#edit_id')},```

Comment: i can also use ```id = (id instanceof Function) ? id().val() : id;```

Comment: That works, too. Using just `id()` gives you more flexibility, since it doesn't have to be an element with a `val()` method.